# onYoutubePlayerAPIReady does not fire

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

In my `index.html` I have

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

which is taken directly from the [Google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

Rather then set a function right after, in my `index.js`, I have added a

`window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = this.onYoutubeReadyCallback.bind(this)`

However I don't always see the `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` function firing. (I have a console log in that function to see when it fires.)

The odd thing is sometimes it fires, and other times it does not.

I can't figure it out. What could be a reason that it is not firing sometimes but is firing others?

Is there some sort of race condition?

Is `window.onYoutubePlayerAPIReady` being added after the script tag is loaded? Is it loaded after the script tag sometimes? What's going on and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue: sometimes the `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` would fire, sometimes it wouldn't. I had to make sure the `youtube.com/player_api` script had to be included AFTER the definition of the `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` function

See the note on this JSFiddle (not mine): http://jsfiddle.net/ramp/4M2YL/

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35956258/3744182) from [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1436303/jeremy) states:

> I had to make sure the `youtube.com/player_api` script had to be included AFTER the definition of the `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady` function

This works, but in addition, don't forget this attribute: `enablejsapi=1`, e.g.:

```
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bqAM6OwzjBg?rel=0&enablejsapi=1&controls=0&showinfo=0"
```